# Can one find an algorithm whose running time is larger than Ackermann's function?

Tags: runtime-analysis

Is there an example of an algorithm whose time complexity is strictly larger than Ackermann's function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$A(n,n)$ is computable. So a trivial algorithm with complexity $O(A(n,n)^2)$ is the following:

1. Compute $x = A(n,n)$.
2. Loop $x^2$ times, doing nothing.

Comment: A(n+1, n+1) has a _hugely_ higher time complexity.